# iOS: Singleton class for storage in UITableView app

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, persistence

I got a app that uses navigation controller and tableViews and I want to create a class to do some simple storage of information that stays persistent while navigating through the different views without saving to disk.

I can either create an `singleton` with only `class method`s, but in this case I´d need to create
the collection class holding the data as an `instance variable` (as @properties don´t work with class methods). I only ever see objects declared in properties in iOS, so is this frowned upon?

The class would look something like this

header:

```
+ (BOOL) addObject: (id) object;
+ (BOOL) removeObject: (id) object;
+ (NSInteger) count;
```

and privately I´ll have an NSArray for storage

```
NSArray *cache;
```

But is this  a good way of achieving the task? or would it be possible to have a non-singelton class with instance methods and use that same instance of the class in the different table views? if so, how would I do that?

Comment: Can you give some more details about what are you doing inside these add and remove object methods ? are you want to store cache array throughout the application ?

Comment: Critical question:  Is there any chance that this data will be accessed by multiple threads?

Comment: (You can certainly use a single instance in more than one place.  They'd be kinda useless if you couldn't.)

Answer (score 0):

First, ALL readwrite properties auto-synthesize instance variables (unless you implement BOTH setter AND getter).
Second, if that information is global to the entire (or most of the) App, a singleton is just what you need. You don't need to keep it as a property (or an ivar). It's a singleton, it keeps its own pointer.
If you still want to go with a property, you will have to pass it some how to every VC in your App (`prepareForSegue:sender:` probably if you're using storyboards).

Answer (score 0):

First figure out what global information you need.  Then figure out what objects you already have that have a lifetime consistent with that global information, and which are logically associated with the info.  Eg, if you need an array of info to "back up" a UITableView, store the pointer to that array in the table view data source instance.

It is rarely necessary to create a "singleton", and having lots of singletons is usually a sign of poor programming.